# Stopping the flow of program until the user has entered text(c#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a program which displays a dialog box(which is a new form).

Now what i want is to stop the execution of the program until user has entered password and pressed Ok Button on the other form.

Problem is whenever i display the dialog box. The underlying program doesnt stop execution and continues anyway.

How can i stop the execution of program until user has entered username and password and submitted them to the main form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `otherForm.ShowDialog()` method when displaying other form to user:

```
using(var otherForm = new OtherForm())
{
    var result = otherForm.ShowDialog(); // main form stops here
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // user entered text and pressed OK button on other form
    }
}
```

[Form.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method shows the form as a *modal dialog box*. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.